# nativeclient ld libstdc++.so.6: invalid DSO for symbol

Tags: libstdc++, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to build a native client application using SDL, and a link error had me stumped. This is the simplest command line that reproduces the error. Has anyone seen this before?

```
\# nacl_sdk/pepper_25/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/i686-nacl-gcc -m64 nacl_glue.cc -lSDL -lppapi_cpp      

/home/rob/nacl_sdk/pepper_25/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-nacl/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-nacl/bin/ld: /home/rob/nacl_sdk/pepper_25/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/../x86_64-nacl/lib/libstdc++.so.6: invalid DSO for symbol `std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4' definition
/home/rob/nacl_sdk/pepper_25/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/../x86_64-nacl/lib/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do C++ examples from NaCl SDK compile successfully?

Comment: Yeah, just tried pepper_25/examples/hello_world_interactive and it compiles fine. Well, I'll start from there and work towards my project and see where it breaks, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use i686-nacl-g++ instead of i686-nacl-gcc.

Digging around a little online, it looks like GCC shouldn't link in the c++ standard library, but my error message looks a little more like it IS linking in the c++ standard library, but is not understanding the symbols it is finding. Weird, but whatever.